# Can you dynamically set a color scheme and/or range in Vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Is it possible dynamically define the color scheme range. For example, I have the below Vega-lite JSON for my color configuration. I would like to input the range below or an entirely different range depending on some condition on the data passed in. Is it possible to set a color range for a variable and dynamically select which one to use?

Also if possible, how would you define the logic to select the appropriate color scheme. The logic is whether some condition on the data (value is present in passed in data) is true. Something like:
`IF VALUE IN datum.COL THEN SCHEME1 ELSE SCHEME2`

What I am trying to do (maybe there is another way around this) is fix the colors for the FIRST (when sorted) one or two values of the `Symbol` field (which may or may not be present) and then have the rest default to a standard color range.

Color Scheme 1:

```
"color": {
          "field": "Symbol",
          "scale": {
             "range": [
                   "#0b9ddb",
                   "#c00000",
                   "#41527a"
                      ]
                   }
         },
```

Color Scheme 2:

```
"color": {
          "field": "Symbol",
          "scale": {
             "range": [
                   "#c00000",
                   "#41527a",
                   "#90ee90"
                      ]
                   }
         },
```

Note, I can get this to work using the following `condition` but the color in the legend does not change. It sticks to the value in the scale range. Is there a way to get the legend to update to use the color from the condition?

```
"color": {
          "field": "Symbol",
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.Symbol == 'Value_0b9ddb'",
            "value": "red"
          },
          "scale": {
             "range": [
                   "#c00000",
                   "#41527a",
                   "#90ee90"
                      ]
                   }
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a transform property which creates a new "calculated" column called: colorScheme then use this in the scale domain encoding.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart that directly encodes color names in the data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"group": "A", "color": "Value_a", "b": 28},
      {"group": "B", "color": "Value_b", "b": 55},
      {"group": "A", "color": "Value_c", "b": 43},
      {"group": "B", "color": "Value_c", "b": 43},
      {"group": "C", "color": "Value_a", "b": 100}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum.color == 'Value_a' ? 'Scheme1' : datum.color == 'Value_b' ? 'Scheme2' : datum.color == 'Value_c' ? 'Scheme3' : 'Scheme4'",
      "as": "colorScheme"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "colorScheme",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["Scheme1", "Scheme2", "Scheme3"],
        "range": ["#0b9ddb", "#c00000", "#000000"]
      }
    }
  },
  "config": {}
}
```